# How to evaluate if a code is correct against a submitted solution

Tags: c, algorithm, compare, evaluate

I´m searching information about how to compare two codes and decide if the code submitted by someone is correct or not (based on a solution code defined before).

I could compare the output but many codes may have the same output. Then I think I must compare someway the codes and give a percentage of similitude.

Anybody can help me?

(the language code is C but I think this isn´t important)

Comment: Most problems can be solved in two or more completely different ways. I think this kind of semantic evaluation is too difficult at present.

Comment: It's undecidable if any given code even finishes. Read about the halting problem.

Comment: If program A's output is identical to program B's output on an adequate set of tests, shouldn't it mean that two programs are essentially similar and solve the same problem?

Comment: What everyone is telling you politely: what you want does not make sense.  For example, which is the correct way to add one to an int variable in C: var++; var=var+1;  Most people prefer the first one, but both are completely correct.  So what you describe means that you are being completely arbitrary.  You are saying getting the right answer is not acceptable - It has to be exactly the way I say it is supposed to be done.

Comment: I think the halting problem doesn´t affect to me, because the submitted codes to compare would be very simply, and I will set a limit time to resolve the problem. If the code exceeds the time then it is not correct.

Comment: It´s for an educational project where the students have to make some c language exercises.The professor for example submit an exercise which description says: Make a code for print at screen the numbers from 1 to 10 separate by comma(Use a for loop). Then the student must use a int variable and iterate a for loop to print the results, but he could give a not correct solution using printf("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10"); . This is why i can´t compare directly the output

Comment: You'd have to define the variable names in the question too. Then you'd have to strip whitespace (taking care to handle `printf (` as well as `printf(`, for example) and use `diff` to compare text files. But that will work only for very simple problems where the solution is quite constrained by the question.  In real life, the professor has to look at each solution and decide for himself what is good or not.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my teachers used online automated program grading systems like http://web-cat.org/

In the assignment they would specify a public api you must provide, and then they would just write tests against your functions, much like unit tests. They would intentionally pick tests that would exploit boundary conditions and other things students are notorious for not thinking about, and just call your code with many different inputs to try to get your code to fail.

Sometimes they would hardcode the expected values, other times they would allow values within a range, and other times they just did the assignment themselves and made it so your own code has to match the results produced by their code.

Obviously, not all programs can be effectively graded this way. It's also kinda error prone in that sometimes even the teacher made a mistake and overflowed an int or something, then the correct student submissions wouldn't match the teachers incorrect results. But, a system doesn't need to be perfect to be useful. But I think this raises an important point in that manually grading by reading the code won't necessarily reveal all mistakes either.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is copy the submitted code, strip out all of the white space and search for substrings that must exist for the code to be correct and/or substrings that cannot exist for the code to be considered correct. The troublesome bit might be setting up to allow for some of the more tricky requirements such as [(a or c),((a or b) and c),((a or b) and c)], where the variables are the result of a boolean check as to if the substring related to the variable exists within the code.

For example, [("printf"),("for"), (not "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10")], would require that "printf" and "for" be substrings in the code, while "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10" i I'm not familiar with C, so I'm I'm assuming here that "printf" is required to be able to print anything without involving output streams, which could be accounted for by something like [("printf" or "out"),("for"), (not "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10")], where "out" is part of C code required to make use of output streams.

It might be possible to automatically find required substrings based on a "correct" code, but as others have mentioned, there are alternative ways to do things. Which is why hard-coding the "solution" is probably required. Even so, it's quite possible that you'll miss a required substring, and it'll be marked as wrong, but it's probably the only way you can do what you ask with some degree of success.

Regular expressions might be useful here.